# Qual è il significato di "tirare i calci" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Matilde interrogata aveva risposto – senza affanno, per la verità – che quella notte Alfredo era in casa loro, nella stalla precisamente, ma perché chiamato da lei per paura che la vacca vecchia crepasse. Andava effettivamente soggetta ad attacchi ed ogni volta sembrava dover **tirare i calci**, e Alfredo di bestie in genere era competente almeno quanto il veterinario condotto, e le sue tariffe inferiori di un quarto.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "tirare i calci" in questo brano? Alla [voce "calcio" del dizionario Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=calcio%201) ho trovato che "tirare un calcio" significa dare un colpo con il piede o con la zampa. Tuttavia, ho l'impressione che, nel passaggio sopra citato, questa locuzione abbia un senso figurato correlato a la "paura che la vacca vecchia crepasse". È cosí?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato di tirare i calci nel contesto da te citato è proprio quello che suggerisci tu, cioè aveva paura che la vacca crepasse.

Infatti capita spesso che un animale mentre muore abbia spasmi violenti che gli fanno compiere movimenti involontari e repentini, tipo tirare calci.

Esiste anche un’altra espressione simile, [tirare le cuoia](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/articoli/parole/decedere.html), che significa morire, crepare.

> In tirare le cuoia, espressione d'ambito d'uso familiare con sfumatura
>   spregiativa, (secondo quanto già annotato dal Tommaseo: «Tirar le
>   cuoja, fam., volg. Modo basso. Morire»), le cuoia sono la forma
>   plurale femminile di cuoio, sostantivo maschile usato propriamente per
>   indicare la pelle conciata di alcuni animali e, con significato
>   estensivo, per designare la pelle umana: secondo alcune
>   interpretazioni, l'espressione potrebbe fare riferimento alla
>   condizione di rigidità che insorge subito dopo la morte.

In piemontese esiste anche un’altra espressione:

> [Tiré i caossèt.](https://it.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Modi_di_dire_piemontesi) Tirare i calzini. Morire.

Comment: In inglese si usa l'espressione "_kick the bucket_" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_the_bucket)

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere la ragione del voto negativo.

Comment: Ultimamente succede abbastanza spesso... Per un po’ ho chiesto di specificare il motivo ma ormai non ci spero neanche più.